# Lemmatize Words not functioning properly

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, lemmatization

I'm trying to do some text mining, with a key intention of taking the words below in this `data.frame`, but combining ones with similar roots:

```
+-------------+------+
|    word     | freq |
+-------------+------+
| best        |  897 |
| see         |  768 |
| received    |  701 |
| questions   |  686 |
| contact     |  663 |
| use         |  659 |
| seat        |  643 |
| information |  640 |
| shipping    |  617 |
| help        |  589 |
| want        |  577 |
| discount    |  549 |
| purchase    |  545 |
| code        |  528 |
| team        |  524 |
| sale        |  503 |
| unsubscribe |  460 |
| website     |  426 |
| love        |  414 |
| buy         |  399 |
| ’m          |  394 |
| furniture   |  388 |
| return      |  387 |
| privacy     |  385 |
| looking     |  383 |
| customer    |  382 |
| receive     |  380 |
| fabric      |  375 |
| interested  |  370 |
| delivery    |  348 |
| intended    |  322 |
| ship        |  322 |
| financing   |  314 |
| •           |  314 |
+-------------+------+
```

The best example is `received` and `receive`. I'd like the final outcome to look like:

```
+----------+------+
|   word   | freq |
+----------+------+
| best     |  897 |
| see      |  768 |
| received | 1081 |
+----------+------+
```

So now, `received` and `receive` and their frequency are summed as one. Additionally, how might I clean out the entries like `’m` and `•`?

Comment: Package udpipe provides lemmatisation. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest you use a different lemmatizer. For example the one provided by `spaCy` which can be used in `R`, for example, by using `spacyr`:

```
# install.packages("spacyr")
library("spacyr")
# install spacy if running for first time
# spacy_install()
spacy_initialize()
spacy_parse("received and receive")

  doc_id sentence_id token_id    token   lemma   pos entity
1  text1           1        1 received receive  VERB       
2  text1           1        2      and     and CCONJ       
3  text1           1        3  receive receive  VERB
```